# Assigning const char* to char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers

```
#include <cstring>

char* str0;
const char* str1 = "abc";


// assign str1 to str0
strcpy(str0, str1);    // syntax correct, but run time error
str0 = str1;           // syntax error, cannot convert const char* to char*
string n_str = str1;
str0 = n_str;          // syntax error, cannot convert ...


cout << str0 << endl;  // expected output: abc
```

I'd like to make str0 same as str1 while runtime(after compilation), I don't know how to do it. And for the case `str0 = str1;` I don't understand why it won't work, because str0 points to nothing, while str1 points to a const string literal, so if I now make str0 point to what str1 is pointing to, it should be fine, but it is not. So it there any way to solve it?

Comment: Where should `strcpy` copy the string? To nowhere? You should first allocate some memory for `str0` to point to.

Comment: Either `strdup` or allocate memory first. Assignment won’t work because it’s `const` and you can’t just remove that with assignment.

Comment: Literals strings (like `"abc"`) are really arrays of *constant* characters. Why would you want a non-constant `char` pointer to such an array? What is the *real* problem you need to solve? Right now this is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the original problem is, there is a class with one of the member data of type char*, and a constructor. The constructor has one of the parameters of type const char*, the constructor should set the member data as what is passed in the constructor parameter. It's part of homework and I'm not allowed to post it online sorry

Comment: Then this might be relevant to you too: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: You don't have to post your actual code, only a simple [mcve] to illustrate the problem, and of course please ask about the actual problem directly instead. In this case you need to dynamically allocate memory for the string in the object, and copy the contents (and don't forget the string null terminator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look one issue at a time

```cpp
strcpy(str0, str1);
```

[strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) copies the characters pointed by str1 into the memory pointed by str0. str1 points to "abc", but str0 doesn't point to anything, hence the runtime error. I would recommend using std::string everywhere so you don't have to manage the memory yourself.

```cpp
str0 = str1;
```

str0 is of type char*, str1 is of type const char*. The const qualifier instructs the compiler to not allow data modification on that particular variable (way over simplified role of const, for more in-depth explanation use your favorite search engine and you should be able to find a bunch of articles explaining const). If you'd be able to assign the same pointer to str0 you'd break the const contract; str0 can be modifiable.

```cpp
string n_str = str1;
```

This is valid because std::string overloads the assignment operator and accepts a const char pointer as the right hand value.

```cpp
str0 = n_str;
```

n_str is of type std::string and str0 is char*, there's no overloaded operator that allows this. If you really want the raw point out of an std::string you can use the c_str() method and it will return you a const char* - I strongly advise against it, unless you have to pass it to a function that only accepts const char*.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::string str0;
const std::string str1 = "abc";

// assign str1 to str0
str0 = str1;

cout << str0 << endl;  // output: abc
```

If you insist on using C:

```
char* str0;
const char* str1 = "abc";

str0 = malloc(strlen(str1) + 1);
// if you use a c++ compiler you need instead:
// str0 = (char*) malloc(strlen(str1) + 1);

strcpy(str0, str1);

// and free after use
// if you use C++ this will not help much
// as pretty much any exception above will cause your code to get out of `free`,
// causing a memory leak
free(str0);
```

If you insist on using bad C++:

```
char* str0;
const char* str1 = "abc";

str0 = new char[strlen(str1) + 1];

strcpy(str0, str1);

// and delete after use
// this will not help much
// as pretty much any exception above will cause your code to get out of `delete`,
// causing a memory leak
delete(str0);
```

Please read about RAII to understand why all of the solutions with manual memory management are bad: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) , [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)

Comment: Please note that in C way you should call `free` afterwards manually to avoid memory leakage

Comment: if I do this, and it works, is it the same as your solution? `char* str0 = new char; const char* str1 = "abc"; strcpy(str0, str1);`

Comment: @keanehui1 no. You allocate mem for just 1 char

Answer (score 1):

Copying `strings` is an expensive operation. But moving `strings` from one place to another is efficient.

casts away the `const`

```cpp
str0 = (char*) str1;
```

or use `std::string` class template library for managing strings. `std::string` owns the character buffer that stores the string value. characters are part of the `string` object. `cont char*` stores the address of such a character buffer but does not own it.

`c_str` returns a `const char*` that points to a null-terminated string. It is useful when you want to pass the contents.

```cpp
std::string str1 = "abc";
char* str0;

strcpy(str0, str1.c_str());
printf(str0);
```

Comment: `str1` is a `const char *`. The `std::string` was `n_str`.

Answer (score 0):

`const` is part of the type, and as such, you can cast it "away". This is considered bad practice, but you should think of `const` as a strong suggestion of the original programmer, not to modify it.

```
const char * str1 = "abc";
char * str2 = (char*) str1;
```